# javafx bindBidirectional binding not working for stage resizble and checkbox slected properties

Tags: binding, javafx-2, javafx

I was trying to achieve simple task,Stage can be resizable if checkbox checked and cannot be resized if checkbox unchecked.

code :

```
 checkBox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(stage.resizableProperty());
```

above code is not working as expected!, i can get the expected results using following code

```
  checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {
            stage.setResizable(checkBox.selectedProperty().getValue());
           }
      });
```

but wonder why bindBidirectional code is not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the Stage class that is fixed in JavaFX 8.0 (which is available in the current Java 8.0 EAP release).

Note that the resizableProperty is actually correctly set when binded bidirectional, the set value has only no effect.

My testing:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StageResizableTest extends Application{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Button button = new Button("resize");

    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        stage.setResizable(true);
      }
    });

    Button button2 = new Button("not resize");

    button2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        stage.setResizable(false);
      }
    });

    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("Resizable");

    checkBox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(stage.resizableProperty());

    checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, Boolean aBoolean, Boolean aBoolean2) {
        System.out.println("checkbox changed from "+aBoolean+" to "+aBoolean2);
      }
    });

    stage.resizableProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, Boolean aBoolean, Boolean aBoolean2) {
        System.out.println("stage resizable changed from "+aBoolean+" to "+aBoolean2);
      }
    });

    Button button3 = new Button("request stage resizable");

    button3.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println(stage.resizableProperty().get());
      }
    });

    VBox box = new VBox();

    box.getChildren().addAll(checkBox, button, button2, button3);

    Scene scene = new Scene(box, 500, 500);

    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've noticed this too... and it's unfortunate as binding properties make the bookkeeping done in your event handlers unnecessary (and presumably with fewer bugs!) So far I've found that writing your own event handler as shown in the examples above seems to be the only thing to do right now. Now having discovered this on my own -- and validated here -- it bothers me a bit that books on the subject matter don't make mention of this bug. For example, I first toyed with this concept with an example taken from **Pro JavaFX 2: A Definitive Guide to Rich Clients with Java Technology**. The first example in Chapter 2 touches on this binding and even makes a special note:

> **Tip**: A property that is bound cannot be explicitly set. In the code
>   preceding the snippet, the resizable property is set with the
>   setResizable() method *before* the property is bound in the next line.

You would think that having gone through the trouble to tell us this, the authors also would've known of this bug. Thank goodness for places like this that help maintain our sanity ;-)